# Selenium webdriver unable to locate element in a dropdown list

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on an element in a dropdown list, and Selenium is able to locate and click the button that makes the list appear, but it doesn't seem to to be able to locate the list itself when it pops up. I have found the HTML that controls the list and tried various find_element_by methods, and none are able to locate it.

I've tried using the Select module, as well as switch_to_frame (which I'm not sure I'm doing correctly), and I've had no luck at all. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Upon further investigation, there appears to be something "off" with the HTML. When I copied the XPATH from  the Chrome inspector, it gave me `/html/body/div[5]/div/div/ul/li[3]/div/button`, however if you notice, the first `div` element is `div[5]`, but looking at the html, there are only 4 `div` elements that are children of the `body`. Also, when I copy the CSS Selector, I get `body > div:nth-child(13) > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > div > button`, but there are only 12 total children of the `body`. Even stranger is the fact that both leaving these locators as they are and attempted to correct for them yield the same results, which is the error.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

url = <url>
browser.get(url)

export1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"react-main-content\"]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/button")
time.sleep(1)
export1.click()

# This is the element it's unable to locate
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[3]/li/button")))

# Execution never reaches this point
export2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[3]/li/button")
export2.click()
```

Here is the HTML (I can't get it to format correctly, so here's a screenshot. The Highlighted section is the drop down I'm looking for):

[image: HTML]

Here is the webpage with the dropdown open and the element in the dropdown I'm trying to locate highlighted.

[image: Dropdown on Webpage]

Comment: What happens when the click occurs?  does the drop down open?

Comment: It does. The export1.click() opens the drop down list, but the WebDriverWait function times out because it's not able to locate the element, even though I can find the HTML that controls it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mistake in an xpath. you have already traversed through the list and you need not do it again. Try this one instead.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[3]/button")))
```

Comment: I think this may be correct. Unfortunately I can't test since the website is down for maintenance at the moment, but after going through the HTML again and figuring out the XPATH manually, the correct path seems to be

`/html/body/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[3]/div/button`

I can't believe that copying the XPATH straight out of Chrome's inspector gave me the wrong path. I'll test later today and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. Tried the xpath you suggested and the one I suspected, and neither worked. Could it have something to do with the dropdown not being in focus somehow? I've heard that, under some circumstances, you need to use the switch_to_frame function, but I'm not sure what frame I'd even pass that function. . .

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Silly me assumed that the HTML from the website being opened in one browser window would match the HTML from the browser window Selenium opens (and seeing as I used the HTML from that same window to locate several other elements, why wouldn't I?). That, however, was not the case.

After pausing execution of my program and examining the HTML of the website in the browser window Selenium opens, I noticed that the location of the element I'm trying to locate is different, so I copied the XPATH from the Selenium browser window and the issue is now resolved.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your problem but something doesn't feel right to me. If you're using chrome in both instances I wouldn't expect there to be any differences in the HTML.

Comment: I'm with you. I didn't think there would be either, but there was. Not sure why honestly.